# como agregar a un widget de wordpress class de bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-widget

veran, estoy diseñando un thema para wordpress y uso bootstrap 4 el inconveniente que tengo es que al registrar un nuevo widget no logro hacer que se le incluya las clases propias de bootstrap 4 esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name'  =>  'widget_1',
        'before_widget' =>  '<section id="widget_1" class="bg-white p-2 mb-2">',
        'after_widget'  =>  '</section>',
        'before_title'  =>  '<h5 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">',
        'after_title'   =>  '</h5>',
    ));
```

y asi es como quiero que se vea si es ejemplo un menu de post recientes

```
<section id="widget_1" class="bg-white p-2 mb-2">
<h6 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0">widget #1</h6>                          
                            <ul class="list-unstyled py-2">
                                <li class="media border-bottom border-gray pb-2">
                                    <img class="mr-3" alt="Responsive image" src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64"/>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h6 class="mt-0 mb-1">List-based media object</h6>
                                        <p><small>July 11, 2017 3</small></p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
<section>
```